# Getting Latest 3 orders by Supplier ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Server code to get information from a combination of 4 tables.

I would like to modify it to only retrieve the latest 3 orders (`pmpOrderDate`) by supplier (`pmpSupplierOrganizationID`).

```
SELECT 
    PO.pmpPurchaseOrderID, PO.pmpOrderDate, PO.pmpSupplierOrganizationID, O.cmoName
FROM 
    PurchaseOrders PO 
INNER JOIN 
    PurchaseOrderLines POL ON PO.pmpPurchaseOrderID = POL.pmlPurchaseOrderID 
INNER JOIN 
    Organizations O ON PO.pmpSupplierOrganizationID = O.cmoOrganizationID 
INNER JOIN 
    Parts P ON POL.pmlPartID = P.impPartID
WHERE 
    P.impPartClassID LIKE 'PUMP%'
```

Can you please help?

EDIT:

I wasn't fully clear on my actual requirements. To clarify further, what I need in the end is to display the latest 3 unique Purchase Orders by Supplier ID based on at least one of the PartClassID for the PartID in the PurchaseOrderLines to have criteria of beginning with string 'PUMP'

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ROW_NUMBER to partition by `pmpSupplierOrganizationID` and order by `pmpOrderDate`.

```
with cteTopOrders AS (
    SELECT PO.pmpPurchaseOrderID, PO.pmpOrderDate, PO.pmpSupplierOrganizationID, O.cmoName,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pmpSupplierOrganizationID ORDER BY pmpOrderDate DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM PurchaseOrders PO 
    Inner Join  PurchaseOrderLines POL ON PO.pmpPurchaseOrderID = POL.pmlPurchaseOrderID 
    Inner Join Organizations O On PO.pmpSupplierOrganizationID = O.cmoOrganizationID 
    Inner Join  Parts P ON POL.pmlPartID = P.impPartID
    WHERE P.impPartClassID Like 'PUMP%'
)
SELECT pmpPurchaseOrderID, pmpOrderDate, pmpSupplierOrganizationID, cmoName
    FROM cteTopOrders
    WHERE RowNum <= 3;
```

Comment: This works, thanks.  However, I am now realizing that it is not giving what I really wanted...Sorry.

Comment: I need the last 3 unique POs per supplier where at least one of the pmlPartID is of impPartClassID like 'PUMP%'.  Is that doable?

Comment: Nice hat! :-) :-)

Comment: @JoeStefanelli,  it looks like your solution was the one that works afterall.  I just added "Distinct" to your last Select clause.  Thanks.

Comment: @NBVC Glad to hear it. Please remember to accept answers that have worked for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ok.  I did.  Previously I was told not to jump to quickly to "Accept" because other solutions may appear that might work better.  This is why I was waiting.  It seems too easy to break rules/standards in this forum.

Comment: @NBVC Your "accept" is never locked in. You can always change it later if a better answer appears.

Answer (score 0):

You need a nested `row_number` to get the three rows per supplier and another OLAP-function on top of it:

```
with OrderRowNum as
 (

    SELECT PO.pmpPurchaseOrderID, PO.pmpOrderDate, PO.pmpSupplierOrganizationID, O.cmoName, P.impPartClassID,
       row_number()
       over (partition by PO.pmpSupplierOrganizationID
             order by pmpOrderDate desc) as rn
    FROM PurchaseOrders PO 
    Inner Join  PurchaseOrderLines POL ON PO.pmpPurchaseOrderID = POL.pmlPurchaseOrderID 
    Inner Join Organizations O On PO.pmpSupplierOrganizationID = O.cmoOrganizationID 
    Inner Join  Parts P ON POL.pmlPartID = P.impPartID
 )
, CheckPUMP as
 (
   select *,
      -- check if at least one of the three rows contains PUMP
      max(case when impPartClassID Like 'PUMP%' then 1 else 0 end)
      over (partition by PO.pmpSupplierOrganizationID) as PUMPflag
   from OrderRowNum
   where rn <= 3 -- get the last three rows per supplier
 )
select * 
from CheckPUMP
where flag = 1
```

Comment: Hi, same comments I gave Joe Stefanelli above.

Comment: Hi dnoeth,  I tried this.  I received error of invalid identifier for OrdersRowNum, but I fixed it by removing the "s" to match your "From OrderRowNum" clause.  Now I am getting error: "The multi-part identifier "P.impPartClassID" could not be bound."

Comment: It's now telling me that 'impPartClassID' is an invalid column name

Comment: You need to add it to the 1st Select

Comment: Now I am getting this error:  Column 'OrderRowNum.pmpPurchaseOrderID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I've been told I should be starting a new thread because of my change in scope.  I am not sure if I should do that now that you've been helping me here?

Comment: The MAX should be a *Windowed Aggregate*, `over` was missing, fixed. You might edit your question and append the additional requirement, cleary stating this changed the original question.

Comment: after correcting the last "flag = 1" to 'PUMPflag = 1', i've got results.  But unfortunately, I am still seeing duplicate POs and also not all the PartClassID are following the criteria of beginning with the string 'PUMP'.  btw, I edited my original question

Comment: I can't follow you, start a new question and show some example data and why you want which rows as result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of lateral joins for this . . . `cross apply`:

```
select p.*, O.cmoName
from Organizations O cross apply
     (select top (3) PO.pmpPurchaseOrderID, PO.pmpOrderDate, PO.pmpSupplierOrganizationID
      from PurchaseOrders PO join
           PurchaseOrderLines POL 
           on PO.pmpPurchaseOrderID = POL.pmlPurchaseOrderID join
           Parts P
           on POL.pmlPartID = P.impPartID
      where PO.pmpSupplierOrganizationID = O.cmoOrganizationID and
            P.impPartClassID Like 'PUMP%'
      order by PO.pmpOrderDate desc
     ) p
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your reply.  It also works for what I described originally.  But now that I see the results, I realize I am really needing the latest 3 unique POs based on at least one of the PurchaseOrderLines.pmPart ID following criteria of Parts.impPartClassID like 'PUMP%'.  Sorry for not realizing this initially.

Comment: @NBVC . . . You should ask a *new* question and not modify this question.  People have gone out of their way to help.  Your modification would invalidate the answers -- and that can attract downvotes.

Comment: Hi Gordon.  Sorry, I didn't know.  dnoeth has been helping with the modifications here now... how do I proceed?